# Why my SQL insert same data when i refresh page ?

Tags: php, sql

I'm new in php coding. I'm creating a comment section but when i submit comment every time same comment inserting into my database.
here is my php code.

```
     <?php 
     function setComments( $mysqli ){
     if (isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])) {
       $uid= $_POST['uid'];
       $date= $_POST['date'];
       $message= $_POST['message'];

      $sql="INSERT INTO comments(uid,date,message) VALUES('$uid','$date','$message')";

    $result = $mysqli-> query($sql);
  }
}
function getComments( $mysqli ){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY date DESC ";
  $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
     while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        echo "<div class='comment-box' ><p>";
        echo $row['uid']."<br><br>";
        echo $row['date']."<br><br>";
        echo nl2br($row['message']);
        echo "<p></div>";
  }
}
```

and here is code for output and submit

```
<?php

 echo "
   <div align='center'>
      <form method='POST' action='".setComments( $mysqli)."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='Anwer'>
        <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>
        <textarea name='message'></textarea>
         <br>
        <button type='submit' name='commentSubmit' > Comment</button>
    </form>
    </div>"
    ;
  getComments($mysqli);

  ?>
```

Comment: @slevy1 please help me

Comment: You are using a function as HTML form action. It's mean this function triggered. You have to use this function after form post event.

Comment: @MehmetSoylu brother i couldn'tunderstand :( can you please explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem. You are calling the save function in runtime without condition. As an example;

```
<?php 
function setComments( $mysqli, $postArr ){
   $uid=  $postArr['uid'];
   $date= $postArr['date'];
   $message= $postArr['message'];
   $sql="INSERT INTO comments(uid,date,message) 
            VALUES('$uid','$date','$message')";
   $result = $mysqli-> query($sql);
}

// I'm calling save function only for submit event

if (!empty($_POST['commentSubmit'])) {
   setComments( $mysqli, $_POST);
}

 // For your HTML code;

echo "<div align='center'>
        <form method='POST' action=''>
          <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='Anwer'>
          <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>
          <textarea name='message'></textarea>
          <br>
          <button type='submit' name='commentSubmit'> Comment</button>
        </form>
    </div>";

getComments($mysqli);
?>
```